# Returning values within an array if it contains a value

Tags: javascript

I have an array that I am trying to return but only return certain rows within that array if the column Free_Agent is populated (or I could do if Years_Kept is greater than or equal to 2).

Here is my code where I have been able to successfully return the values of the array by a console log. Everything I try when I either try to do a forEach or pull the filtered data via a filter view I have set up (363219995) will not work.

```
async function gsrun(cl){

    const gsapi = google.sheets({version:'v4', auth: cl });
    gsapi.spreadsheets.values.get({
        spreadsheetId: "11e5nFk50pDztDLngwTSmossJaNXNAGOaLqaGDEwrbQM",
        range: 'Keepers!C1:F',
        
    }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        const rows = res.data.values;
        if (rows.length) {
          
          rows.map((row) => {
            console.log(`${row[0]}, ${row[1]}, ${row[2]}, ${row[3]}`);
          });
        } else {
          console.log('No data found.');
        }

       
    })

};
```

[Terminal Screenshot of mapped Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIJqO.jpg)

Can anybody please help a newbie? I've been teaching myself and watching videos and reading everything I can, I just can't seem to grasp it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to filter the values (rows) arrays to check if there is a value.

```js
async function gsrun(cl){

    const gsapi = google.sheets({version:'v4', auth: cl });
    gsapi.spreadsheets.values.get({
        spreadsheetId: "11e5nFk50pDztDLngwTSmossJaNXNAGOaLqaGDEwrbQM",
        range: 'Keepers!C1:F',
        
    }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        const rows = res.data.values;

        if (rows.length) {
          const cells = rows.filter(cell => cell[3])
          cells.map((cell) => {
            console.log(`${cell[0]}, ${cell[1]}, ${cell[2]}, ${cell[3]}`);
          });
        } else {
          console.log('No data found.');
        }

       
    })

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to @ArthurCosta's answer, based on the second condition you provided.

```js
async function gsrun(cl){

    const gsapi = google.sheets({version:'v4', auth: cl });
    gsapi.spreadsheets.values.get({
        spreadsheetId: "11e5nFk50pDztDLngwTSmossJaNXNAGOaLqaGDEwrbQM",
        range: 'Keepers!C1:F',
        
    }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        const rows = res.data.values;

        if (rows.length) {
          const cells = rows.filter(cell => cell[3] || (parseInt(cell[2]) >= 2))
          cells.map((cell) => {
            console.log(`${cell[0]}, ${cell[1]}, ${cell[2]}, ${cell[3]}`);
          });
        } else {
          console.log('No data found.');
        }

       
    })

};
```